# How do you update a value with a path in complex object in Redis/ReJson on Kubernetes?

Tags: c#, database, kubernetes, redis, azure-aks

I am trying to update a complex object via a path value which it appear ReJson can do.
I have used it as a Cache just fine, I want to use it as a json collection store for real time data (similar to mongodb).

for example:
{
"name": "Michael \u0027Mike D\u0027 Diamond",
"employeeID": "E#101",
"role": "Cleaner",
"location": {
"longitude": -2.552079,
"lattitude": 51.501335
},
"numberOfAssignedJobs": 5
}

For example I want to update **location.lattitude** without taking the whole object and dealing with read/write sync issues.

However I am struggling with the API/How it is used in kubernetes. If anyone has any example code or tips and tricks, anything is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `JSON.GET` command and JSON path syntax ([docs here](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/path/))

First, save the document in Redis at key "jsondoc":

```
127.0.0.1:6379> json.set jsondoc $ '{ "name": "Michael \u0027Mike D\u0027 Diamond", "employeeID": "E#101", "role": "Cleaner", "location": { "longitude": -2.552079, "latitude": 51.501335 }, "numberOfAssignedJobs": 5 }'
```

Atomically update path `location.latitude` to some other value:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> json.set jsondoc $.location.latitude 52.014
OK
```

Retrieve just `location.latitude`:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> json.get jsondoc $.location.latitude
"52.014"
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I did end up using this command via a C# Libraries NReJson & StackExchange.Redis! Have a great day!